# How to make clickable text in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble figuring out how to make it so that the text is clickable and redirects to my Dashboard.js and About.js. Could someone help me out? I tried using Router but couldn't figure out how to get it to work. Thanks

```
function App() {
  return (
    /** 
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Nav/>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
    */
    <div classname="App">
      <Container fluid>
        <Row style={{
            paddingTop: '250px',
          }}>
          <Col sm={3} style={{
              marginLeft: 'auto',
              marginRight: 'auto',
              marginRight: '0px'
            }}>
            <div class="container--wrap" style={{
                height: '60vh',
                borderRadius: '15px'
              }}>
              <p style={{
                  textAlign: 'center',
                  color: 'white',
                  paddingTop: '600px',
                  fontSize: '50px',
                  fontWeight: 'bolder'
                }}>
                  ABOUT
              </p>
            </div>
          </Col>
          <Col sm={3} style={{
              marginLeft: 'auto',
              marginRight: 'auto',
              marginLeft: '0px',
              marginRight: '0px',
            }}>
            <div class="container--wrap" style={{
                height: '60vh',
                borderRadius: '15px'
              }}>
              <p style={{
                  textAlign: 'center',
                  color: 'white',
                  paddingTop: '600px',
                  fontSize: '50px',
                  fontWeight: 'bolder'
                }}>
                SIGN UP
              </p> 
            </div>
          </Col>
          <Col sm={3} style={{
              marginLeft: 'auto',
              marginRight: 'auto',
              marginLeft: '0px'
            }}>
            <div class="container--wrap" style={{
                height: '60vh',
                borderRadius: '15px'
                }}>
              <p style={{
                  textAlign: 'center',
                  color: 'white',
                  paddingTop: '600px',
                  fontSize: '50px',
                  fontWeight: 'bolder'
                }}>
                DASHBOARD  
              </p> 
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am trying to make the text "ABOUT" "SIGN UP" and "DASHBOARD" clickable and change the page to the correct js file.

Comment: it would be easy to debug if you could paste your code in  https://codesandbox.io/ and share the url here

Comment: Have you tried `onclick` and `history.push`?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-wood-9ico3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: for using react-router you can wrapping your text by <Link to="/about">ABOUT</Link> tag

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the text with a button,

```
const message = () => {
console.log("Hello World!") 
}
return (
<button onClick={message}> Press me to print a message! </button>
);
```

Comment: how can i have it so that it changes the page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the text similar to an anchor link. You can try using the React Link tag.

```
<Router>
 <Link to='https://google.com/'><button>GO GOOGLE</button></Link>
</Router>
```

or to another component

```
<Link to={ROUTES.HOME}> //with ROUTES.HOME pointing to the location of your component in a <Route>
 Home
</Link>
```

Here's a link to a document.
https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html

Answer (score 0):

Your  `<div classname="App">` should be inside of the `<Router>` then you can add Link to your element for example in your about case:

```
<p style={{
              textAlign: 'center',
              color: 'white',
              paddingTop: '600px',
              fontSize: '50px',
              fontWeight: 'bolder'
            }}>
             <Link to={About}>
            ABOUT
            </Link>
          </p>
```